# JSONObject return empty:false

Tags: java, json, org.json

After some researchs, I didn't have found any solutions to this problem:
when I create a JSONObject (org.json) from a file, it return "empty":false. Why does it return this and how can I fix it?

Java:

```
JSONObject config = new JSONObject(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("config/maj.json")));
```

JSON:

```
{"FyloZ":"0"}
```

Files.readAllLines is working return the right value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Files.readAllLines()` returns `List<String>`, not a `String`.

So actually you are using the following constructor (accepting a single `Object` parameter):

https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject-java.lang.Object-

> Construct a JSONObject from an Object using bean getters

The only getter-style method of a `List` is `isEmpty()`, so you get that 'empty: false' thing.

Try the following:

```
String json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("config/maj.json")), "utf-8");
JSONObject config = new JSONObject(json);
```

Here we read JSON as bytes, convert them to a string (assuming it's in `utf-8`) and then create a `JSONObject` from it.